# YouTube Splashscreen not working correctly

Tags: html, youtube

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/qe5kcps2/`

```
<div onclick="myDiv=document.getElementById('myDiv'); myDiv.style.display='block';
    this.style.display='none'">
    <a style="display:inline-block;background-color:#097065; width: 266px; height: 266px;
        cursor: pointer; border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #BF598E;">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="266" height="266" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?rel=0;disablekb=1&amp;vq=medium&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;fs=0'"
        style="background-color:#000000; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;
        border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #711B93;"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

My question is, how come when you click off to the right side of the image (white empty space) it opens without clicking directly on the image? Is there any code that can be implemented to fix it so that you have to click on the image for it to open?

Comment: Please share YouTube url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a style="width:266px" to the first div (the onclick one). by default it's taking up 100% of the width of the window so clicking on the white space you're actually clicking that div with the onclick event :)

```
<div style="width:266px" onclick="myDiv=document.getElementById('myDiv'); myDiv.style.display='block';
    this.style.display='none'">
    <a style="display:inline-block;background-color:#097065; width: 266px; height: 266px;
        cursor: pointer; border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #BF598E;">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="266" height="266" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?rel=0;disablekb=1&amp;vq=medium&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;fs=0'"
        style="background-color:#000000; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;
        border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #711B93;"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: added updated code with the extra style attribute ;)

Comment: Can you help me with this, it's about another code? https://jsfiddle.net/zL5b22bb/1/

Comment: I'm trying to get it to where you can have 2 color borders while keeping the hyperlink invisible with onmouseover working.

Comment: Add 'color:white;' to style, and that's it Here: https://jsfiddle.net/fcdy4ocw/4/ Hyperlink is invisible now. Thanks.

Comment: You can post your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883477/trying-to-get-invisible-hyperlink