# Trying to get invisible hyperlink

Tags: html

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/zL5b22bb/1/

Code 1. This is the original code showing the hyperlink border after you click on the image. It's clearly visible.

```
<a href="http://5645646/" target="_blank">
<img style="display:inline-block;background-color:#000000; width: 100px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer;border: 5px solid #0F16FD;"
onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/ra4471G.png';
this.style.color='white'
this.style.border='5px solid #66A4F2'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png';
this.style.color='white'
this.style.border='5px solid #0F16FD' "  
/></a>
```

Code 2. After I remove the "img tag" the the hyperlink border is not visible. Which is what I want. But, by removing "img tag", the onmouseover background image gets disabled which is what I don't want.

```
<a href="http://5645646/" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block;background-color:#000000; width: 100px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer;border: 5px solid #0F16FD;"
onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/ra4471G.png';
this.style.color='white'
this.style.border='5px solid #66A4F2'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png';
this.style.color='white'
this.style.border='5px solid #0F16FD' "  
/></a>
```

Code 3. Now the hyperlink is invisible after you click on it, but the borders double up onmouuseover which messes it all up.

```
<a href="http://5645646/" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block;background-color:#000000;color:white; width: 100px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer;border: 5px solid #0F16FD;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png" width="100px" height="100px"
onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/ra4471G.png';
this.style.border='5px solid #66A4F2'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png';
this.style.border='5px solid #0F16FD' "  
/>
```

Everything is in the jsfiddle link.

I'm trying to get it to where you can have 2 color borders while keeping the hyperlink invisible with onmouseover working.

---

Is there a less complicated method than doing this? https://jsfiddle.net/fcdy4ocw/4/

```
<a id="test" href="http://5645646/" target="_blank" style="color:white; display:inline-block;background:#000000 url(http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png);width:100px;height:100px;cursor:pointer;border:5px solid #0F16FD;" onmouseover="this.style.border='5px solid #66A4F2';
this.style.background='#000000 url(http://i.imgur.com/ra4471G.png)';" onmouseout="this.style.border='5px solid #0F16FD';
this.style.background='#000000 url(http://i.imgur.com/awwMlPD.png)';"></a>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding *exactly* what it is you *want*. It *seems* like a simple [CSS hover state](https://jsfiddle.net/fcdy4ocw/5/) would be much easier.

Comment: I only wanted to use html, no css. I assume the only way to do it via html is the answer I provided then.

Comment: Would you by any chance be able to help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886709/how-many-different-ways-can-you-add-a-splashscreen-to-a-youtube-video-via-html

Comment: **You are using CSS**. The only difference is you've got it all inline rather than external. Inline CSS works, but can be problematic if you ever want to change it or want more than 1 element to be styled the same. `this.style` is just adding a layer of javascript to write CSS.... but it's *still* css. You're essentially just stating "Javascript, write this inline css"

Comment: How would you do it using inline CSS?

Comment: Can you show me using that method?

Comment: To be frank, I wouldn't ever use inline CSS for this. Inline CSS is **always** problematic when updates are needed. I would add the CSS to the header of the HTML file.... optimally I would use an external CSS file.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks for your help.